# TypeError ('module' object is not callable) using dateutil relativedelta

Tags: python, import, typeerror

I'm trying to use `dateutil` and `relativedelta` to retrieve the difference between two dates (`runwayMonths`) but I'm getting `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` and can't figure out why.

I assume the issue is with how I'm calling the class and/or module but I can't find a similar example on here or elsewhere that helps me understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from dateutil import relativedelta

today = datetime.date.today()
runwayDays = 529
dropDeadDate = today + timedelta(days=runwayDays)
runwayMonths = relativedelta(today,dropDeadDate)
```

I could understand if I was screwing up the formatting for the parameters for `relativedelta` as I'm a total noob but the error seems to suggest the issue is with the module or class. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 22):

`dateutil.relativedelta` is a module, and the `relativedelta()` function is inside it.

Try this instead:

`from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta`